Where should generic toy identification questions go?
Based on this question from the close queue and prior discussion on meta, I'm wondering: is there an appropriate place within StackExchange to discuss generic toy identification questions?
I've found quite a few random bits in bins of supposed LEGO that would be good to identify.  I'm not suggesting that Bricks.SE is the right venue for this, but it would be nice to know where to send folks, if there is such a place.

I don't think there's such a site.
A few days ago, user @Rand'alThor compiled a list of Stack Exchange sites accepting identification questions: Which SE sites accept "identification" questions? but there is simply no Stack Exchange website for toys in general.
